# How can I handle empty Cells with my macro in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to remove the first 4 characters from every cell. In my code I first look what the last row is and then tell the program to run until this point. It only works if in the selected column are no empty cells. if there are empty ones the program stops at the first empty cell. I tried some loops but the never worked...

Here is my code:

```
Sub datei_format_prefix()

Dim Zelle As Range
Dim bCell As Range

find_last_row

For Each bCell In Selection

    Range(bCell.Address).Select
    Range(bCell.Address).Offset(1, 0).Select


   Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select


   For Each Zelle In Selection
       If Zelle.Value Like "*_*" Then
           Zelle.Value = Right(Zelle, Len(Zelle) - 4)
       End If

       If Zelle.Value Like "?########" Then
           Zelle.Value = Right(Zelle, Len(Zelle) - 1)
       End If
   Next
Next

End Sub
Sub find_last_row()
Dim rownum As Integer
Dim SelRange As Range

Set SelRange = Selection

Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
rownum = Selection.Row + Selection.rows.Count - 1
MsgBox rownum


SelRange.Select

End Sub
```

Some Data:

```
|This is Row 1 of Excel Sheet with some Buttons in it|
|    Heder1    |  Header2   |   Header3    |
|--------------|------------|--------------|
| JFG_12345678 | Production | ABC_12345678 |
| JFG_12345678 | Production | ABC_12345678 |
| JFG_12345678 | Production | ABC_12345678 |
| JFG_12345678 | Production |              |
|              | Production | ABC_12345678 |
|              | Production |              |
| JFG_12345678 | Production | ABC_12345678 |
```

Comment: Always better, when looking for the last row, to work from the bottom up.  So to find Last Row in Column A:  `rownum = Cells(Rows.count,1).end(xlUp).row` Note that this will default to the active sheet.  If another sheet might be active, you'll need to properly qualify.

Answer (score 2):

That should be easy. the problem appears to be that you are trying to return a value <= 0 when using `Right`. There are a couple of approaches you could take:

```
For Each Zelle In Selection
    Dim ZelleValue As Variant
    ZelleValue = Zelle.Value

    'If ZelleValue  <> vbNullString Then ' If Cell Isnt Blank.
    'This is what you're asking for, but will still allow errors.
    If Not IsError(ZelleValue) Then
        If Len(ZelleValue > 1) Then
            If Len(ZelleValue) > 4 Then
                If ZelleValue Like "*_*" Then
                    Zelle.Value = Right(ZelleValue, Len(ZelleValue) - 4)
                End If
            End If

            If ZelleValue Like "?########" Then
                Zelle.Value = Right(ZelleValue, Len(ZelleValue) - 1)
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Note that I added the conditional for checking for a blank cell, but commented it out. The reason is that you really should be checking that the length of your cell meets expectations. If, for example, you try to use a value less than zero as an argument to right or left, you will receive an error. To avoid this, we make sure that we can return `Len(ZelleValue) - 4)` and `Len(ZelleValue) - 1` before calling these conditionals. In turn, we will skip blanks as well as cells not meeting the expectation (such as `"f_o"` which is `Like "*_*"` but `Len("f_o") - 4` equals `-1`).

Comment: +1, but `Zelle.Value` should be checked with `IsError` *before* assigning it to `ZelleValue` - comparing an error value with a string or anything other than, well, an *error value* (or checking its length with `Len`), results in a very common *type mismatch* run-time error.

Comment: thanks partly works now. it removes the prefix from the one next line after the first empty cell. have to get the selection right now i guess so it selects till the end of the table.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Good catch. Added that check.

Comment: in datei_format_prefix where i use xlDown, how does the loop have to look like if i want it to run until the last line of the table? excel crashed every time at my previous attempts.

Comment: @wenzel267 it shouldnt be adjusting the wrong cell, since the for loop is only working one cell at a time (but this is a good time to note that selection is rarely if ever a good course of action). You may want to step through the code (F8) and see if you can follow it as it works.

Comment: I just realized that you have a `For Cell in Selection` loop inside of a `For Cell in Selection` loop. Not a very good idea. Let me edit my answer to improve that a bit.

Comment: @wenzel267 In trying to refactor your code I am completely confused on your intent. Your `find_last_row` method (presumably) expands your selection to the body of a table, but then you are iterating over each cell in this range, and then operating on the offset column of this cell. This makes no sense to me. What are you trying to do? Can you provide an example of your data?

Comment: My attempt is more like putting things together from the internet because I am new to vba. The user should be able to select multiple header and in these columns every prefix should be removed. Therefore I used offset to get from the header cell to the first cell of data. Finding the last row isnt realy a problem. It may not look good but im glad it works somehow. If there are no empty cell in a column it works fine. but when there are empty cells it doesnt work properly anymore. I think there must be some kind of Loop around    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select.

Comment: to get the selection of the whole column of data. But i dont know how. Also added some example data.